# Steam installation error in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, steam

Steam shows an installation error while installing from the .deb package also from Ubuntu software center.

```
error :
Couldn't set up the Steam Runtime. Are you running low on disk space?
Continuing...
```

How do I fix this?

```
intel@intel-H61M-DS2:~$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1       125G   16G  104G  14% /
none            4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            4.2G  4.1k  4.2G   1% /dev
tmpfs           836M  1.5M  835M   1% /run
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            4.2G   18M  4.2G   1% /run/shm
none            105M   33k  105M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdc3       864G  200G  665G  24% /media/intel/backup
/dev/sda3       791G  294G  498G  38% /media/intel/BC6AE4A56AE45DA0
/dev/sda2       210G  151G   60G  72% /media/intel/C0B0A9CCB0A9C96C
/dev/sdb1       1.1T  991G  9.4G 100% /media/intel/665A8B675A8B333B
```

Comment: Run `df -H` in a terminal. And paste the results in the question. This is for viewing your disk space info.

Comment: @ethanbmnz done

Comment: On what filesystem is steam installed? /dev/sdb1 seems full and could be why Steam can't load.

Comment: its on sdc1 @ShadowMitia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these [instructions](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3134-TIAL-4638):

- Run `steam --reset` in a terminal.
- Restart your computer.

This should reset/reconfigure the steam files properly.

Comment: actually installing it from synaptic package manger fixed it,tnx for taking your time to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

OP's own answer:

Installing steam using the synaptic package manger fixed it...